# sequelize sync is not a function

Tags: mocha.js, sequelize.js, truncate

I am trying to set up a test using mocha with sequelize. I'd like to truncate all the table and create new ones before and after each test. I thought I could just use `sequelize.sync`.

Here is my test:

```
import chai from "chai";
import assert from "assert";
import app from "../../src/app";
import chaiHttp from "chai-http";
import factories from "../factories";
import Sequelize from "sequelize";

// import dotenv from "dotenv";
// dotenv.config({path: ".env.test"});
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe("'regions'service", () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await Sequelize.sync({ force: true });
  });

  it("should POST area", async () => {
    const region = await factories.create("region");
    const dummy = {
      name: "New area",
      open: true,
      description: "This is a cool area!",
      gps: "122.123, 123.4123",
      regionId: region.dataValues.id
    };
    const res = await chai
      .request(app)
      .post("/api/areas")
      .send(dummy);
    assert.equal(res.body.name, dummy.name);
  });
});
```

My error message:

> ```
>  TypeError: _sequelize2.default.sync is not a function
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I understood sequelize all wrong. I have to use sequelize to make the connection everytime when trying to use it.

so change the file to :

```
import chai from "chai";
import assert from "assert";
import app from "../../src/app";
import chaiHttp from "chai-http";
import factories from "../factories";
import db from "../../src/models";

// import dotenv from "dotenv";
// dotenv.config({path: ".env.test"});
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe("'regions'service", () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await db.sequelize.sync({ force: true, logging: false });
  });

  it("should POST area", async () => {
    const region = await factories.create("region");
    const dummy = {
      name: "New area",
      open: true,
      description: "This is a cool area!",
      gps: "122.123, 123.4123",
      regionId: region.dataValues.id
    };
    const res = await chai
      .request(app)
      .post("/api/areas")
      .send(dummy);
    assert.equal(res.body.name, dummy.name);
  });
});
```

Where my db file looks like the following:

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json")[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config
  );
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (
      file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
    );
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    var model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```